# Selenium C# : How do I count elements whose href contains a certain substring?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to Selenium C#. I want to count the number of elements ( image below) whose href contains a specific subsring ("/Dashboards/CustomDashboards"). I tried using this:
`driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href='/Dashboards/CustomDashboard']")).Count;`

But it returned 1 whilst the number I am looking for is 25. I couldn't use the partial link selector because that does not refer to the href. Help would be appreciated. Thanks :)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Count` worked correctly because you are looking for exactly `/Dashboards/CustomDashboard`

If you want to `Count` all the elements that **contain** `/Dashboards/CustomDashboard` (i.e. with an ID after) you want to change the search to:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href*='/Dashboards/CustomDashboard']")).Count;
```